# Cannot use align environment even after including `amsmath`

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

The following code works as expected when running Python 2. The expected output is an empty Matplotlib frame along with some parameter values arranged neatly in a box. I have shown the output after the source code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# For Enabling Latex inside plots
plt.rcParams.update({                                                                 
  "text.usetex": True        ,                                                               
  "font.family": "serif"     ,
  "font.serif": ["Palatino"] ,       
 })
custom_preamble = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    "text.latex.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage{amsmath}", # for the align enivironment
        r"\usepackage{xcolor}",  # for coloring texts 
        r"\usepackage{mathtools}"  
        ],
    }
plt.rcParams.update(custom_preamble)

def display_input_params(fig,ax,lb, dx, W, eps):
     """ Show input parameters on the canvas
     """
     from decimal import Decimal

     text1 = r'\begin{align} '
     text2 = r'\Aboxed{\ell &= '    + str(round(lb,2)) +  '}' + '\\\\'
     text3 = r'dx &= '              + str(round(dx,3))        + '\\\\'
     text4 = r'W &= '               + str(W)                  + '\\\\'
     text5 = r'\varepsilon &= '     + '%.5f'%Decimal(eps) 
     text6 = r'\end{align}'
     text = text1 + text2 + text3 + text4 + text5 + text6 
     props = dict(boxstyle='square', facecolor='white', alpha=0.0, pad=0.9)
     ax.text(0.1, 0.95, text, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
             verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)

#-------------------------------------------

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

lb  = 0.1
dx  = 0.1
W   = 0.4
eps = 0.01

display_input_params(fig,ax,lb,dx,W,eps)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, when I execute the same program unedited in Python 3, I get an empty Matplotlib frame with none of the parameters displayed and the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.                                                                            

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.                                                               
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.                      
 ...                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                       
l.19 {\rmfamily \begin{align}                              
                              \Aboxed{\ell &= 0.1}\\dx &= 0.1\\W &= 0.4\\\va...                                        
No pages of output.                                        
Transcript written on 540edcf8dd085e46a955ab19c1561106.log.
```

Why is it unable to detect the `align` environment when I have included the `amsmath` package that is required for it?

I include the full error output below

```
~/Desktop ❯ python test.py                                   base 04:06:27 AM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 233, in _run_checked_subprocess
    report = subprocess.check_output(
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', '../540edcf8dd085e46a955ab19c1561106.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py", line 455, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 436, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 73, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2810, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 3082, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 685, in draw
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(renderer)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 317, in _get_layout
    w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 259, in get_text_width_height_descent
    w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 335, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 271, in make_dvi
    self._run_checked_subprocess(
  File "/home/smilingbuddha/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 241, in _run_checked_subprocess
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'\\\\begin{align} \\\\Aboxed{\\\\ell &= 0.1}\\\\\\\\dx &= 0.1\\\\\\\\W &= 0.4\\\\\\\\\\\\varepsilon &= 0.01000\\\\end{align}'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../540edcf8dd085e46a955ab19c1561106.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/cm-super/type1ec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/underscore/underscore.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file 540edcf8dd085e46a955ab19c1561106.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ppl.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

! LaTeX Error: Environment align undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.19 {\rmfamily \begin{align}
                              \Aboxed{\ell &= 0.1}\\dx &= 0.1\\W &= 0.4\\\va...
No pages of output.
Transcript written on 540edcf8dd085e46a955ab19c1561106.log.
```